# Prompt box, ask value, store in cell. Add button for adapt

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to the world of google sheets. I was able to program very simple routines in Excel. Sorry if I couldn't find the answer anywhere on this site.

My question is simple, has 2 parts:

1. I would like to prompt a question box on opening the google sheet, asking a numeric value, after answering this, storing the numeric value to a specific cell, e.g. B3.
2. I would like to have a button on multiple pages of the sheet, prompting the same question box to edit the value.

Background:

I'm a medical doctor, I've created a sheet with many medications for small children in emergency situations. I would like a ask the user the age (and maybe later the weight, it's now calculated) of the child, so the age and weight are correct on all pages and the user is not in a hurry to find the right cell. If the user would like to edit the age, he uses the button, available on all sheets.

Comment: There are many ways to do that. Use the [prompt()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#prompt(String,ButtonSet)) for the msgbox in an [onOpen()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onopen) that will [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)). Another way is to [use google forms with sheets](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/lmVvZ0sNyN4) and an [onFormSubmit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit())

Answer (score 4):

First, with the following function you can ask the user for the age and set it to a specific cell in a specific sheet:

```
function promptUserAge()
{
  // Prompt for the value
  var age =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Please enter the age.").getResponseText();

  // Get the sheet that you want store the value in and set the value in the cell B3
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Patient Information").getRange("B3").setValue( age );  
}
```

Now, since you used the phrase

> so the age and weight are correct on all pages

I am not sure if you are going to set the value in multiple sheets, and are you going to do that with Sheets functions or app script. That is why I am going to include the method to set the value in all sheets, in specific cell:

```
function promptUserAge()
{
 // Prompt for the value
 var age =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Please enter the age.").getResponseText();
 //Get all pages in spreadsheet and iterate through
 var sheets =   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
 for(var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++ )
 {
  //Set the value in the cell B3 of the page
  sheets[i].getRange("B3").setValue( age );
 }  
}
```

To get the prompt to pop-up when user opens the Spreadsheet you use call it in the onOpen function:

```
function onOpen(e)
{ 
  promptUserAge();
}
```

And now, the part where you add the button to edit the value.

You could add a custom menu that would appear in the Spreadsheet's toolbar with a custom menu like this :

```
 function createMenu()
 {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Fill information")
            .addItem("Age", "promptUserAge")
            .addToUi();
 }
```

This is a good way if your users know what to look for, meaning that you have told them the custom menu exists. From my experience, some people have trouble finding the menu even if you tell them it is there, so since your background suggests you want to create an easy and fast way I would use the second method:

You could insert an image to the Spreadsheet by navigating from it's toolbar: Insert -> Image. Insert an Image that says 'Push here to edit information' in a very clear way and right click the image. You get the borders to edit the image size and in it's upper-right corner appears three dots. You click the dots and then "Assign script...". To the prompt, insert the function name without the parenthesis. In this example you would insert:

```
  promptUserAge
```

Now the image works as a button to call the function.

I hope this helped.