# Google Sheets sidebar form to pass data to specific sheets and specific cells

Tags: html, google-apps-script, sidebar

Novice here using Google Apps Script. I've tried to use a couple other articles to try to solve my issue but I'm stuck. I've got a similar situation as this article: [Prompt box, ask value, store in cell. Add button for adapt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46864923/prompt-box-ask-value-store-in-cell-add-button-for-adapt) but I need to use a sidebar form and pass data from the sidebar to specific cells on specific sheets. The script was originally set up to appendrow and that works but when I adjust it to try to fill specific cells on specific sheets, I've broken the code somewhere. Thanks for any help!

Here's the Google apps script I'm using:

```
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp
   .getUi()
   .createMenu("Admin")
   .addItem("Admin page", "showAdminSidebar")
   .addToUi();
}

function showAdminSidebar() {
 var widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Form.html");
 widget.setTitle("Admin page");
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(widget);
}

//I've tried several things and can't figure out how to modify this section to send data to specific cells on specific sheets.
function appendRowFromFormSubmit(form) {
 var ss =     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetByName("Schedule").getRange("G5").setValue(     firstName ); 
 var ss =     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetByName("Meals").getRange("C3").setValue( lastName    ); 
}
```

and the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <base target="_top">
   <script>
     function submitForm() {
       google.script.run.appendRowFromFormSubmit(document.getElementById("employeeForm"));
     }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Enter employee details</h1>
   <form id="employeeForm">
     <label for="firstName">First name</label>
     <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"><br><br>
     <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
     <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"><br><br>
     <div>
       <label for="department">Department:</label><br>
       <input type="radio" id="sales" name="department" value="Sales">
       <label for="sales">Sales</label><br>
       <input type="radio" id="marketing" name="department" value="Marketing">
       <label for="marketing">Marketing</label><br>
       <input type="radio" id="product" name="department" value="Product">
       <label for="product">Product</label><br>
       <input type="radio" id="engineering" name="department" value="Engineering">
       <label for="engineering">Engineering</label><br><br>
       <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm();">
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
function appendRowFromFormSubmit(form) {
  var ss =     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetByName("Schedule").getRange("G5").setValue(     firstName ); 
  var ss =     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetByName("Meals").getRange("C3").setValue( lastName    ); 
}
```

To

```
function appendRowFromFormSubmit(form) {
  let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spread.getSheetByName("Schedule").getRange("G5").setValue(form.firstName); 
  spread.getSheetByName("Meals").getRange("C3").setValue(form.lastName); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion TheWizEd. Unfortunately that didn't work for me but thanks again!

Comment: I copied your side bar and `appendRowFromFormSubmit(form)` and it works for me.   Is there is a error in the execution log?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I deleted the function and re-wrote it and it worked!! Thank you again so much!